# can an acid alkalinize blood

Tags: medical-science, nutrition

I have recently read that umeboshi vinegar **alkalinizes** blood thanks to its content in acetic acid.

I find at least strange that an acid can have an effect contrary to acidification.

Can this be found in any reliable source ?